# How to fix 'Kernel driver not accessible' in VirtualBox?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, permissions, virtualbox

I install `virtualbox` on Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS, but after install and create new virtual Host shows this error:

> Kernel driver not accessible. Abort.

However it definitely has read and write permissions, in `/dev/` :

> crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root     10,    58 kwi  1 13:45 vboxdrv

How to address this `Kernel driver not accessible` error?

Comment: Do you have secure boot enabled?

Comment: Do you have virtualization enabled for your CPU in the BIOS?

Comment: Secure boot is disabled. I had virtualization for CPU enabled in BIOS, however I disabled it, tried running the machine and it worked for a while then closed itself saying that I need to enable virtualization. I did that and, I have absolutely no idea why, it works great now! No errors, everything works fine. So I guess the solution was disable virtualization, try to run it, enable virtualization and then it all works? Thanks a lot @Eagle_Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had virtualization for CPU enabled in BIOS, however I disabled it, tried running the machine and it worked for a while then closed itself saying that I need to enable virtualization. I did that and, I have absolutely no idea why, it works great now! No errors, everything works fine. So I guess the solution is as follows: disable virtualization, try to run it, enable virtualization and then it all works.